# How to update SQL Batch?

Tags: sql

In my client place they have a database. Once I complete the incremental changes on database, I have prepare the list of SQL object changes in one SQL file.

The script is like this:

```
If sql object 1 present in database 
   DROP the SQL object 1
GO

create the SQL Object 1 

If sql object 2 present in database 
   DROP the SQL object 2

create the SQL Object 2
```

All the time I have drop the existing Object and re-create the same.

Now this batch may contains some error.

My requirement is that if there any error in file the file. non of the the sql objects has been re-created. it should rollback the old sql objects.

If there is no error then it would create all the SQL objects.

Due the `GO` statement in middle I could not able to user the TRANSACTION in sql.

How can this be solved?

Comment: You can use `GO` inside a transaction assuming you are running the script from a utility that understands it as a batch delimiter

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `GO`, then. Simply remove it from your script, and add your `BEGIN` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` commands where you need them.

```
BEGIN TRAN

   IF EXISTS Object1
   BEGIN
        DROP Object1;
   END 
   CREATE Object1;

   IF EXISTS Object2
   BEGIN
        DROP Object2;
   END 
   CREATE Object2;

COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying database schema via DROP/CREATE has many problems:

- it may loose data
- it looses permissions and extended properties added to the objects dropped
- cross object dependencies (eg. foreign keys) require a certain order of drop/create

Usually is better to try to ALTER the object from schema version to schema version. This requires you to know which schema version is currently deployed, but that problem is easily solvable (use a database extended property, see [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/)).

Back to your question, a naive approach is to wrap your entire script in a big BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT but that seldom works:

- it creates a potentially large transaction that requires much log space.
- the result is impossible to validate until *after* the commit when is too late to do anything about it
- the behavior mingling exceptions and transactions is messy at best. [`XACT_ABORT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) helps somehow, but only so much.
- **Not all DLL statements can be run from inside a transaction**

For these resons I would recommnd a much simpler and safer approach: take a backup, [`WITH COPY_ONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191495.aspx), of the database before modifying the schema. If anything goes wrong, rollback to the copy. Alternative, a database snapshot can be used as a backup. See [How to: Revert a Database to a Database Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189281.aspx).

Note that BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT can span batches (ie. can be separated by multiple `GO`) so your concern is not an issue.